# How do I update all package references in a C# solution to most recent Nuget version

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have a Visual Studio, C# solution with several projects. Some of those point to older versions of some packages.  my local nuget repo has more current, stable versions.  e.g.

[image]

What I want to do is update all those old 3.0.246-alpha references to the latest stable version, 3.1.0

What is the best way to do that?

Output window after clicking Install:
[image]

errors at top of screen:
[image]

This is what I want to fix.  There is no version 3.0.246 of that module,  so I want Nuget to overide it with latest stable version, 3.1

Comment: Click "install"??

Comment: yup, tried that, came back to the exact same screen and didn't change the version

Comment: @gbritton Please [edit] your question to include the output of the nuget execution from the "Output" tab when you try to install the update. It might show you an error message you need to fix.

Comment: The output tab does not have nuget info, but I posted it anyway

Comment: How about clicking "Update" at the top of the screen?

Comment: @LarryBud yup, tried all the usual buttons, including "Update" before posting.  It always comes back to the same error

Answer (score 0):

Due to the limitation, I post this as an answer, but may include some comments.(Sorry for that)

As I searched online(nuget.org), I found no packages called TBSM.*, perhaps they were created by yourself/your company… and just used(saved) locally?

From the error message, it reported that the NuGet package was not found on source XXXXX, so did you perform some operations to remove the old version of the NuGet packages? (Maybe also removed the NuGet cache files?)

**I did some tests:**

Since I don’t know the specific structures of your projects/NuGet Package, I just created two NuGet packages for test locally with same names(ID) and different versions, and then added the package source path to the settings, and installed the first NuGet package into one project, after that deleted this NuGet package and the cache files. Then tried to `Update` it, NuGet Package manager could still update it to the latest version successfully, even if I uncheck these options: `Allow NuGet to download missing packages` and `Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio` from VS > Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General.

Of course, I may not remove all of the NuGet packages’ cache files, or the issue is cause by the specific NuGet packages’ structures(cause I used two NuGet packages, but yours maybe used the same one with something updated)…

**What I suggest:**

1). If it is possible, you can have a try `Uninstall` and then `Install` the relates version.(remember to make a backup before this)

2). Try to select this two options in VS(Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General), “Allow NuGet to download missing packages” and “Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio”, and then click `Clear All NuGet Cache(s)` button. Make sure you have added the right path source from VS > Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources and try to install/update the NuGet packages again.(Generally, clear cache will not cause errors, but please remember to make a backup before clearing cache)

Comment: yes, these are local packages and old versions *were* removed.  Just can't figure out where/what to change to make Nuget stop looking for the old, removed packages and grab the latest ones instead

Comment: @gbritton, have you tried to uncheck this two options: `Allow NuGet to download missing packages` and `Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio`, and then restart VS to try again?